# jQuery running C# method

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, webmethod

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

I am trying to get an output from a C# method through Javascript/jQuery.

The output returned is **`[object Object]`** when it should return a capital city.

jQuery (using jqvmaps tool):

```
$(document).ready(function () {



    var Capital = null;

    jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap(
{

    map: 'world_en',
    backgroundColor: '#a5bfdd',
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderOpacity: 0.25,
    borderWidth: 1,
    color: 'gray',
    enableZoom: true,
    hoverColor: 'orange',
    hoverOpacity: null,
    normalizeFunction: 'linear',
    scaleColors: ['#b6d6ff', '#005ace'],
    selectedColor: 'red',
    selectedRegion: null,
    showTooltip: true,
    onRegionClick: function (element, code, region) {

        var codeValue = $('#Code').text();
        var countryCode = $('#Code').text();

        var data = null;
        data = { CountryCode: codeValue.toUpperCase() }


        console.log(data);


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'Default.aspx/GetCapital',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (code) {

                Capital = code.d;

                CapitalCity.text(Capital);

            }
        });

        var ISOCode = $('#Code');

        ISOCode.text(code);

        var Country = $('#Country');

        Country.text(region);


        var CapitalCity = $('#Capital');




    }
});



    });
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

namespace WorldMapDetails
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {



        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

            }
        }

        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static string GetCapital(string CountryCode)
        {
            //do your stuff
            Country Country = new Country();

            List<Country> selectedCountry = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Country>>(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Brian\Documents\Bloxinations\Bloxinations\WorldMapInfo\WorldMapDetails\Scripts\json\Countries.json"));

            String Capital = null;

            foreach (Country c in selectedCountry)
            {
                if (c.cca2 == CountryCode)
                {
                    Capital = c.capital.ToString().ToUpper();
                }
            }

            return Capital;
        }
    }
}
```

If I run this jQuery instead it works just fine but the changing of the Capital City text is 'delayed' (I have to double click on a region).

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var Capital = $('#Capital');

    jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap(
    {

        map: 'world_en',
        backgroundColor: '#a5bfdd',
        borderColor: 'white',
        borderOpacity: 0.25,
        borderWidth: 1,
        color: 'gray',
        enableZoom: true,
        hoverColor: 'orange',
        hoverOpacity: null,
        normalizeFunction: 'linear',
        scaleColors: ['#b6d6ff', '#005ace'],
        selectedColor: 'red',
        selectedRegion: null,
        showTooltip: true,
        onRegionClick: function (element, code, region)
        {

            var codeValue = $('#Code').text();
            var countryCode = $('#Code').text();
            var data = { CountryCode:codeValue.toUpperCase() }

            var ISOCode = $('#Code');

            ISOCode.text(code);

            var Country = $('#Country');

            Country.text(region);



            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'Default.aspx/GetCapital',
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (code) {

                    Capital.text(code.d);
                    //console.log(data);
                    console.log(code);

                }
            });

        }



    });


});
```

How can I fix it so that it updates immediately (without the need for double clicking)?

Answer (score 0):

Fix assigning of ajax result to `Capital` variable as below.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    var Capital = null;

    jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap(
{

    map: 'world_en',
    backgroundColor: '#a5bfdd',
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderOpacity: 0.25,
    borderWidth: 1,
    color: 'gray',
    enableZoom: true,
    hoverColor: 'orange',
    hoverOpacity: null,
    normalizeFunction: 'linear',
    scaleColors: ['#b6d6ff', '#005ace'],
    selectedColor: 'red',
    selectedRegion: null,
    showTooltip: true,
    onRegionClick: function (element, code, region) {

        var codeValue = $('#Code').text();
        var countryCode = $('#Code').text();

        var data = null;
        data = { CountryCode: codeValue.toUpperCase() }

        console.log(data);
        var Capital = null;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'Default.aspx/GetCapital',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (code) {
                Capital = code;
                $('#Capital').text(Capital);
            }
        });

        var ISOCode = $('#Code');

        ISOCode.text(code);

        var Country = $('#Country');

        Country.text(region);
    }
});



    });
```

Comment: Still the same problem. Need to double click.

Comment: I mean you need to apply my fix in the first set of JS where you was updating CapitalCity.text(Capital).

Comment: Yes, I understood. Still the same error. See udpated code (first part).

Comment: it is still wrong CapitalCity.text(Capital); can not work as CapitalCity element variable is yet not created and why code.d as i can see you send string from service call, see my updated answer.